# Rescatar datos de datos en phpmyadmin para recibirlos en un formulario

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación donde me aparezca un index que contenga los datos de libros previamente almacenados en phpmyadmin. No consigo como hacer para que en cada apartado me coja los datos almacenado en la tabla de phpmyadmin. Es decir que por ejemplo me coja los datos del precio. 
Dejo parte del código`

```
<head>
    <title>Libro</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="estilos/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contenedorPrincipal"/>

        <div class="cabecera"><img src="imagenes/banner.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="navegacion">
                <a href="listarlibros.php">Ver libros</a>
                <a href="formulario.html">Añadir libro</a>
        </div>

        <div class="contenido">

                <div class="portadaLibro">
                    <img src="imagenes/universo.jpg" />
                    <h2> <form method="post"  > $precio </h2><br>
                    <a class="btnComprar" href="#">Añadir a la cesta</a>
                </div>

                <h1>El Universo en tu mano</h1>


                <p>Christophe Galfard, el mejor discípulo de Stephen Hawking, es uno de los divulgadores científicos más renombrados del planeta.</p>

                <table class="datosLibro">
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <th>Autor</th>
                        <td>Christophe Galfard</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Editorial</th>
                        <td>Blackie Brooks</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <th>Año de edición</th>
                        <td>2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Género</th>
                        <td>Ensayo</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>`
```

Comment: Donde esta tu codigo php que has usado para hacer lo que quieres? Échale un ojo a PDO.

Comment: lo que quiero saber es como puedo coger los datos de phpmyadmin desde un formulario de html